# Image Array Validation Does Not Work Laravel StoreRequest Its store directly to database..still * null data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The provided code integrates Laravel validation, displaying error messages if image upload rules are not met. The JavaScript onchange event updates image previews dynamically. Ensure the correct application of validation rules for each image input.

```
<div class="border border-outlin-dashed p-4">
                            <label for="" class="fw-bold fs-6 mb-5">banner</label>
                            <input id="file_banner" class="form-control form-control-solid mb-5 mb-lg-2 @error('images.banner') is-invalid @enderror" 
                                type="file" name="images[banner]" placeholder="Choose File" 
                                onchange="document.getElementById('preview_image_banner').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" 
                                accept="image/*"
                            >
                            @error('images.banner')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="symbol-2by3 flex-shrink-0 text-left mb-2 w-25">
                                <img id="preview_image_banner" src="{{ isset($edit_data->images['banner']) ? $edit_data->images['banner'] :asset('images/placeholder.png')  }}" class="img-fluid" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="border border-outlin-dashed p-4">
                            <label for="" class="fw-bold fs-6 mb-5">thumbnail</label>
                            <input id="file_thumbnail" class="form-control form-control-solid mb-5 mb-lg-2 @error('images.thumbnail') is-invalid @enderror" 
                                type="file" name="images[thumbnail]" placeholder="Choose File" 
                                onchange="document.getElementById('preview_image_thumbnail').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" 
                                accept="image/*"
                            >
                            @error('images.thumbnail')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="symbol-2by3 flex-shrink-0 text-left mb-2 w-25">
                                <img id="preview_image_thumbnail" src="{{ isset($edit_data->images['thumbnail']) ? $edit_data->images['thumbnail'] :asset('images/placeholder.png')  }}" class="img-fluid" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="border border-outlin-dashed p-4">
                            <label for="" class="fw-bold fs-6 mb-5">featured</label>
                            <input id="file_featured" class="form-control form-control-solid mb-5 mb-lg-2 @error('images.featured') is-invalid @enderror" 
                                type="file" name="images[featured]" placeholder="Choose File" 
                                onchange="document.getElementById('preview_image_featured').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" 
                                accept="image/*"
                            >
                            @error('images.featured')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror

                            <div class="symbol-2by3 flex-shrink-0 text-left mb-2 w-25">
                                <img id="preview_image_featured" src="{{ isset($edit_data->images['featured']) ? $edit_data->images['featured'] :asset('images/placeholder.png')  }}" class="img-fluid" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The Store Function // The store method receives a validated request with blog data, including images. If images are present, it saves them, then invokes a service to store the blog data with associated image paths. Finally, it redirects to the blog page with a success message.

```
 public function store(BlogStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $imagePaths = $this->saveImages($request->file('images'), 'blog');
        } 

        $result = $this->service->storeBLog($data,$imagePaths);

        return redirect()->route('blog')->with('success', 'Blog Created Successfully');
    }
```

BlogStoreRequest.php
In the rules method, the validation logic ensures that the 'images.banner', 'images.thumbnail', and 'images.featured' inputs must be valid image files with specified formats and a maximum size of 2048 KB. In the messages method, custom error messages are defined to inform users that choosing an image for each of the mentioned categories is mandatory. These rules and messages are part of the Laravel FormRequest validation process, enhancing user experience by providing clear instructions and validation for the images associated with the banner, thumbnail, and featured sections of a blog post.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'images.banner' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
            'images.thumbnail' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
            'images.featured' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'images.banner.required' => 'You must choose image.',
            'images.thumbnail.required' => 'You must choose image.',
            'images.featured.required' => 'You must choose image.'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Solved
sorry I forgot to add   required|
return [
            'images.banner' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
            'images.thumbnail' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
            'images.featured' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ];

Comment: How does the request look that you receive in your formrequest? Does it contain the correct data? Also, how does your form in the view look like? Does it have the `                     enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute? This is needed if you want to upload files.

Comment: yeas thanks I missed to add require @Sitethief thanks for notice me

Comment: I suggest you add your own answer to this question and accept that as the correct one.

Comment: yeah whatever thanks you are the first answer of my stackoverflow laravel question @Sitethief